# Find Pips value - 3 to 5 Digits forex pricing calculation

Tags: python, string, digits, forex

Nb in Python asking! Trying to subtract price (trade opened) with price.1 (trade closed) to get number of pips formatted properly without decimal. However, I could not proceed due to restriction involving split x lists.The, I was trying the solution below: , but, seems to be reduntant .. 
I have created 4 lists and 4 loops to transform float to string, change the format to proceeed with subtraction. Any idea how to get correct number formatted ?  Something to go directly into column (results) float .. if 3 digits before punctation decimal . . do 1000*100.. If one digit before . .. *100/10.

```
    # Price Trade Opened
    listp = []
    listpf = [] 
    for i in df2['Price']:
        listp.append(format(i,'.5f'))

    for i in listp:
        listpf.append(str(i))

    # Price.1 trade closed.

    listpp = [] 
    listppf = []

    for i in df2['Price.1']:
        listpp.append(format(i,'.5f'))

    for i in listpp:
        listppf.append(str(i))


     # Transform list into DF and remove punctuation. Thereby, I could 
        subtract. 

     df3 = pd.DataFrame(listp)
     col = ['Price']
     df3.columns = col
     df3 = df3.stack().str.replace('.', '').unstack()

     df4 = pd.DataFrame(listpp)
     col = ['Price1']
     df4.columns = col
     df4 = df4.stack().str.replace('.', '').unstack()

     dfc = pd.concat([df3, df4], axis=1)
     dfc.fillna(0)
     dfc.replace({'nan': 0}, inplace=True)

     dfc['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(dfc['Price'])
     dfc['Price1'] = pd.to_numeric(dfc['Price1'])
     dfc['Result'] = (dfc['Price'] - dfc['Price1'])
     dfc.head()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to calculate the difference between open and close values, and divide by the relevant multiplier for the pair.  Like this:

```
def pip_calc(open, close):
    if str(open).index('.') >= 3:  # JPY pair
        multiplier = 0.01
    else:
        multiplier = 0.0001

    pips = round((close - open) / multiplier)
    return int(pips)


pip_calc(112.65, 112.68)
# 3

pip_calc(1.6566, 1.6568)
# 2
```

Comment: Just closed with:                                                                                 
        results = []

        for i,ii in zip(df2['Price'], df['Price.1']):
        if str(i).find('.') >= 3:
              multiplier = 0.01
        else:
             multiplier = 0.0001
        if str(ii).find('.') >= 3:
            multiplier = 0.01
        else:
           multiplier = 0.0001
    pips = round((i - ii) / multiplier)
    results.append(pips)                                                                           df2['Pips'] = results
df2.head()